# Adding a JPanel to a JPanel with layouts

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel that shows my main gui on it. On that main panel I want to add other JPanels that show the description of a item and allow you to buy it and sell it. I am using FlowLayout for both my main panel and my ItemPanel. Here are the classes:

**MainPanel**

```
package me.phination.clicker.gui;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    private JLabel batchLabel;
    private JButton btnMakeBatch;
    private JButton btnSellBatch;
    private JLabel moneyLabel;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JPanel itemPanel;


    public MainPanel() {
        setBackground(new Color(153, 51, 0));
        SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
        setLayout(springLayout);

            //add the item panel to this panel
        itemPanel = new ItemPanel();
        itemPanel.setSize(200, 100);
        add(itemPanel);
    }

    public void consoleMsg(String msg) {
        textArea.append(msg + "\n");
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }
}
```

**ItemPanel**

```
package me.phination.clicker.game;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;

public class ItemPanel extends JPanel {
        public ItemPanel() {
                SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
                setLayout(springLayout);

                JLabel lblItemName = new JLabel("Item name");
                lblItemName.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.BOLD, 18));
                springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblItemName, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
                add(lblItemName);

                JLabel lblAmountOwned = new JLabel("Amount owned");
                springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblAmountOwned, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
                springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblItemName, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, lblAmountOwned);
                springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblAmountOwned, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, this);
                add(lblAmountOwned);

                JButton btnPurchase = new JButton("Purchase");
                springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, btnPurchase, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, lblItemName);
                springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, btnPurchase, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, this);
                add(btnPurchase);

                JButton btnSell = new JButton("Sell");
                springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, btnSell, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, this);
                springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, btnSell, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, btnPurchase);
                add(btnSell);

                JLabel lblDescription = new JLabel("Description");
                springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblDescription, 6, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblItemName);
                springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblDescription, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, lblItemName);
                add(lblDescription);
        }
}
```

The issue that I am having is if I use the Spring in ItemPanel, when I add it to the main panel it just shows nothing. If I don't use a layout in ItemPanel it shows perfectly fine, but it doesn't have the pretty layout that ItemPanel has if I add it to the JFrame by itself.

Comment: Post code, not links.

Comment: There is no problem adding a JPanel to another JPanel, both of them having their own layouts.  Make sure each element on each panel is only on that panel.  Post code here, not on a different site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't put any constraints on your ItemPanel for SpringLayout, so it doesn't expand or know how much to take up within the MainPanel. When I added constraints to the panel it appeared. Try adding this and see if your panel appears.

```
springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, itemPanel, 22, SpringLayout.SOUTH, btnMakeBatch);
springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, itemPanel, 43, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, itemPanel, -104, SpringLayout.EAST, this);
```

Are you designing this by hand and then pressing Run to view it, or using, for example, [WindowBuilder](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/)?

Comment: I decided to try out WindowBuilder to learn how different layouts worked. In the past I always just used no layout and did all the positions manually. Now that I understand better how SpringLayout works, I will try to stay away from WindowBuilder. That worked though, thanks.

Comment: I actually meant you should be using it if you aren't. When I opened the GUI up in WindowBuilder, I saw your ItemPanel shrunk up in the corner, because it had no anchors attached to it. Dragging it around allowed it to be resized and properly anchored. Basically, if something doesn't look like, try manually adjusting it in Windowbuilder's Drag and Drop GUI until it looks about right, and then fine-tune in the code what you actually want it to do.